# Editing MSI file to add new drivers

Tags: windows, windows-7, windows-installer, windows-7-x64

I have a VPN checkpoint file with a driver which is causing lot of BSOD on laptops, I have new driver which can be replace old version. Does anyone know how I can replace the driver but also make sure windows validate this. I have msi package and thew new driver in .sys format.

I try using windows Msidb.exe but it dose not extract the drivers or let me add one.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [ORCA editor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa370557%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) from Microsoft.
However this tool is no more supported and editing an MSI is not an easy task.
Take a look also to the other tools present in the same page above

[Found here](http://www.technipages.com/download-orca-msi-editor.html) a link where you can download it individually

Comment: I need to change a file ( drivers .sys file), this software allows you to change some properties.

Comment: I have found [this page](http://www.symantec.com/connect/blogs/add-file-msi-using-orca) with a workaround to add files to ORCA. Let me know if it works.

Comment: this page is not clear it ask me do things but i dont know where to add this information.

Answer (score 0):

Also you can use the [InstedIt](http://www.instedit.com/) more useful and functional tool than ORCA.
Concerning your question to change file in msi (schema is similar as in post about ORCA):

1. In **Component** table create a new component (you need specify the
   destination directory).
2. In **FutureComponents** associate new component with the main future.
3. In **File** table you can delete the old file and create a new with the same name, associate it with new component, set attributes to Compressed (0x4000) and set sequence. The sequence     should be the last one in file table+1 (to determinate which one is last you can sort files by sequence).
4. In **Media** table you need to create a cab (InstedIt can do it without additional soft), to do it create a new row with the next parameters DiskId - uniq, LastSequence - your sequnce number from step 3, and name of cabinet - any but with .cab extension. And then right click on the this row and chose the "Rebuild selected CABs", it genarates error with path where should be your new file on disk. Put file here and one more time generate the cab.
5. Return to **Component** table and associate the KeyPath param with your file.

It should work, but if have any question - you are welcome.